# call href click on document.ready

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, doc

a have two aspx pages **page1.aspx** and **page2.aspx**.
i have an `href` in **page1.aspx**  `<a id="GoHref" href="page2.aspx">`
i want that when users click `docHref` to be redirected to **page2.aspx** and download a doc file via an automatic click on `<a id="DocHref" runat="server">`

page2.load is as below:

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       if(!IsPostBack)
            DocHref.HRef="./mydoc.doc";
    }
```

i 'd like to do do an automatic click on `document.ready`, something like this:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {

         $('#DocHref').trigger('click');

    });
```

But it doesn't work !!
is this a good way to download a doc file ? Or there a better server side way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user Consider putting more effort into your question (punctuation, grammar, ...).

Comment: The problem may be that the client side ID of your hyperlink is being changed by .Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off using the window .location property than simulating clicks as there is far less overhead.

```
<a id="myLink" href="somewebsite.com">My Link</a>

$(function() {
   window.location.href = $("#myLink").attr("href");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have html like so:

```
<a id="myLink" href="somewebsite.com">My Link</a>
```

To have jQuery simulate a click:

```
$(function() {
  $("#myLink").click();
});
```

Comment: Can't find the link but I remember reading somewhere that simulating clicks should be avoided.

Comment: @James South, he asked.. I answered :)

Comment: @Nick... I've actually used your solution in the past myself.